# How to reset variable in C in infinite loop back to 0?

Tags: c, variables, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have had this issue for some hours now. I have tried plenty of solutions, but maybe I am missing something here.

After I run my code and set time for:

```
11
59
57
```

Clock starts working and count 11:59:58 > 11:59:59 > 12:00:00 > 12:00:01

I want to make the clock reset back to the 00:00:01 value once it hits 12:00:00, but I don't know how. It just always exceeds the number.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

/* Scanf example:
    05
    11
    40
    */ // this will start the clock from the time 05:11:40

int main()
{
    int time;
    int hours, minutes, seconds;
    int delay = 1000; // we will add a delay of 1000 milliseconds which we will call Sleep function
    time = hours;
    time = minutes;
    time = seconds;

    printf("Set time: \n");
    //printf("\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &hours, &minutes, &seconds);

    if(hours > 12 || minutes > 60 || seconds > 60){

        printf("ERROR\n");
        printf("You need to set time according to hours:minutes:seconds");
        exit (0);
    }

    while(1){                                       //This is an infinite loup
        seconds++;
        if(seconds > 59){
            minutes++;
            seconds = 0;
        }
        if(minutes > 59){
            hours++;
            minutes = 0;
        } 
        if(hours > 11 && minutes > 59 && seconds > 59){
               time = 0;
          }
           
        printf("\n Clock :");
        printf("\n %02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds );
        Sleep(delay); // This function slows down the while loop and make it look like a real clock
        system("cls"); // this function clears the screen
        
    
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(hours > 11 && minutes > 59 && seconds > 59)` ==> `if (hours > 11)`

Comment: You have working code for `seconds` and `minutes`, you just need to do the same for `hours`.

Comment: @pmg Nope, that unfortunatelly did not work.

Comment: This is a good time to start learning how to debug programs, you will need to do that to succeed.  In an IDE you could single-step, or without one you could add extra printf statements to show you the values of hours, minutes, seconds at each step.  Either way would have shown you that when the loop begins at 11:59:59, the seconds and minutes change to (0, 60) then (0, 0) before your final if statement.  You can also become a human-powered IDE and do the single-step yourself by working through the code on paper with the time at 11:59:59.

Comment: You don't use `int time` anywhere: `if(hours > 11)` *`hours`* `= 0;`

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: You may want to read this official help page: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I need help with "tick" I simply can not see the button or anything to mark right answer. I see your comments but I see only small flag on the left, I googled I read here how to do it, but simply description is different that what I see.

Comment: You cannot accept any answers because your answer has no "official" answers. The answers you got were in the form of comments, not answers. However, as already stated, you can write your own answer.

Comment: But I dont want to take credit from @Someprogrammerdude, he helped me, he got the right answer

Comment: In the answer, you can write "As pointed out in the comments section", to give credit to the comments. If you want, you can also explicitly mention someone's username in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Someprogrammerdude got it right in the comments. Thank you!

```
if(hours > 11 && minutes > 59 && seconds > 59){
           time = 0;
      }
```

Into

```
if(hours > 11){
           hours = 0;
      }
```